# Updating Swift Syntax for MKMapRect Extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, mapkit, swift5

I'm using an extension that helps the pins on my map to cluster and expand when tapped. With the update from Swift 4 to Swift 4.2 and now Swift 5, my app cashes whenever I use the suggested new Swift Syntax.

Here is my current code in Swift 4:

```
extension MKMapRect {
init(minX: Double, minY: Double, maxX: Double, maxY: Double) {
    self.init(x: minX, y: minY, width: abs(maxX - minX), height: abs(maxY - minY))
}
init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double) {
    self.init(origin: MKMapPoint(x: x, y: y), size: MKMapSize(width: width, height: height))
}
var minX: Double { return MKMapRectGetMinX(self) }
var minY: Double { return MKMapRectGetMinY(self) }
var midX: Double { return MKMapRectGetMidX(self) }
var midY: Double { return MKMapRectGetMidY(self) }
var maxX: Double { return MKMapRectGetMaxX(self) }
var maxY: Double { return MKMapRectGetMaxY(self) }
func intersects(_ rect: MKMapRect) -> Bool {
    return MKMapRectIntersectsRect(self, rect)
}
func contains(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    return MKMapRectContainsPoint(self, MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate))
}
}
```

I'm getting the error "'MKMapRectGetMinX' has been replaced by property 'MKMapRect.minX'" for all my of variables.

Here is the updated Swift 5 syntax that isn't working:

```
extension MKMapRect {
init(minX: Double, minY: Double, maxX: Double, maxY: Double) {
    self.init(x: minX, y: minY, width: abs(maxX - minX), height: abs(maxY - minY))
}
init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double) {
    self.init(origin: MKMapPoint(x: x, y: y), size: MKMapSize(width: width, height: height))
}
var minX: Double { return self.minX }
var minY: Double { return self.minY }
var midX: Double { return self.midX }
var midY: Double { return self.midY }
var maxX: Double { return self.maxX }
var maxY: Double { return self.maxY }
func intersects(_ rect: MKMapRect) -> Bool {
    return self.intersects(rect)
}
func contains(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    return self.contains(MKMapPoint.init(coordinate))
}
}
```

With this new syntax, all paths through this function will call itself. Hoping someone can give me some alternatives.

Comment: You can just delete the ones that give the warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply don't need any of the properties that are related to the points, since they already exist in Swift 5 with the same name you gave them. The same is true for `intersects`.

All you need are your custom initializers and the `contains` method.

```
extension MKMapRect {
    init(minX: Double, minY: Double, maxX: Double, maxY: Double) {
        self.init(x: minX, y: minY, width: abs(maxX - minX), height: abs(maxY - minY))
    }

    init(x: Double, y: Double, width: Double, height: Double) {
        self.init(origin: MKMapPoint(x: x, y: y), size: MKMapSize(width: width, height: height))
    }

    func contains(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return self.contains(MKMapPoint.init(coordinate))
    }
}
```